# Regexes: How to use the length of a match in the replacement expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, ssms

I'm trying to write a regex that will reformat some boilerplate SQL code into a cleaner version of itself. Here's an example.

I have:

```
SELECT
    [Person].[Name]
    [Person].[Address],
    [Sales].[TotalAmount]
```

I want:

```
SELECT
    [Name]        = [Person].[Name],
    [Address]     = [Person].[Address],
    [TotalAmount] = [Sales].[TotalAmount]
```

I can write an expression to move the field name to the left-hand side of the assignment statement, no problem. The tricky part is getting the spacing right – is there some way to use the length of the match in the replacement? And additionally, to use the length of the longest match? So that "[Name]" would be followed by length("TotalAmount") - length("Name") = 7 spaces, "[Address]" would be followed by length("TotalAmount") - length("Address") = 4 spaces, and so on?

I'm not sure this is possible with regular expressions, but I thought I'd throw it out there in the hope that there is some regex guru who knows how to do this.

Comment: A RegEx in what language/environment?

Comment: Sorry, SQL Server Management Studio, which I believe uses the same dialect as Visual Studio.

Comment: Yeah, you'll have to do some juggling in a tool. RegEx alone can't get you that (you've hit an exact limitation of regexes - state "counting").

Comment: That's what I was starting to think, and yeah... I'm not going to write a parser to clean up my SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> <sub>**Off language but still going to post it.**</sub>

In PHP there is [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg-replace-callback) which let you match a string with regex and then process it with PHP. So here's a full PHP solution, note that you need **PHP 5.3+**:

```
$sql = 'SELECT
    [Person].[Name]
    [Person].[Address],
    [Sales].[TotalAmount]';

preg_match_all('#\[[^]]+\]\.(\[[^]]+\])#', $sql, $found); // Match
$max = max(array_map('strlen', $found[1])); // Find max length

$new = preg_replace_callback('#\[[^]]+\]\.(\[[^]]+\])#', function($m)use($max){
    $string = $m[1].str_repeat(' ',$max - strlen($m[1])).' = '.$m[0]; // Constructing
    return($string);
}, $sql);
echo $new;
```

**Output:**

```
SELECT
    [Name]        = [Person].[Name]
    [Address]     = [Person].[Address],
    [TotalAmount] = [Sales].[TotalAmount]
```

<kbd>**[Online demo](http://ideone.com/pa4A3y)**</kbd>

Comment: That's a great answer. I may have to drop that into a PHP script for the sole purpose of cleaning up my SQL code. Thanks!